# c# printing with equal margins

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, c#-4.0, c#-3.0

Is there way to find coordinates of center of paper?

I had read many of discussions, forums and tips - and I'm not able to do it.
Im printing like this:

```
     using (PrintDialog pd = new PrintDialog())
     {
        if (pd.ShowDialog() != DialogResult.OK) return;
        PrintDocument document = new PrintDocument();
        document.PrinterSettings = pd.PrinterSettings;
        document.PrintPage += new PrintPageEventHandler(Document_PrintPage);
        document.Print();
    }

    private void Document_PrintPage(object sender, PrintPageEventArgs e)
    {
        int X = (int)e.PageSettings.PrintableArea.X;
        int Y = (int)e.PageSettings.PrintableArea.Y;
        int width = (int)e.PageSettings.PrintableArea.Width - X;
        int height = (int)e.PageSettings.PrintableArea.Height - Y;

        int centerX = (width - X)/2 + X;
        int centerY = (height - Y)/2 + Y;

        e.Graphics.DrawRectangle(Pens.Gray, new Rectangle(X, Y, width, height));
        e.Graphics.DrawLine(Pens.Black, centerX - 100, centerY, centerX + 100, centerY);
        e.Graphics.DrawLine(Pens.Black, centerX, centerY - 100, centerX, centerY + 100);
    }
```

Of course I tried calculating these coordinates in many ways, including use of MarginBounds, Hardmargins, Margins etc.

Anyone knows how to print something exactly on a center of paper?

Answer (score 0):

`e.PageBounds` is what you are looking for(a property of `PrintPageEventArgs`). It gives you the rectangular area that represents the total area of the page.

```
int centerX = e.PageBounds.Width / 2;
int centerY = e.PageBounds.Height / 2;
```